# Debian/Ubuntu set preseed mirror variable via early/run command

Tags: ubuntu, debian, preseed

I need to know how can I add this to preseeding via d-i early/command or d-i preseed/run to set my mirror inside `preseed.cfg` from `/proc/cmdline` argument.

If I do:

```
d-i preseed/run string ws/ubuntu.sh

#!/bin/sh
     for x in `cat /proc/cmdline`; do
             case $x in RPHOST*)
                     eval $x

                     d-i mirror/http/hostname string ${RPHOST}
                     d-i mirror/http/mirror string ${RPHOST}
                     d-i apt-setup/security_host string ${RPHOST}
                     ;;
             esac; 
done
```

it fails.

It works well in the CentOS kickstart `%pre` section but i have no clue how to do it via debian/ubuntu preseeding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

after some research on debconf i came up with this solution:

in your preseed.cfg you call the script via:

```
d-i preseed/run string ws/ubuntu.sh    // subdir from preseed file location
```

content of ubuntu.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Start ubuntu.sh runscript" >> /var/log/syslog
for x in `cat /proc/cmdline`; do
        case $x in RPHOST*)
                eval $x
                HOST=$RPHOST
                echo "d-i mirror/http/hostname string ${HOST}" > /tmp/mirror.cfg
                echo "d-i mirror/http/mirror string ${HOST}" >> /tmp/mirror.cfg
                echo "d-i apt-setup/security_host string ${HOST}" >> /tmp/mirror.cfg
                ;;
        esac;
done
// add´s values to /var/lib/cdebconf/question.dat
debconf-set-selections /tmp/mirror.cfg
```

works good @ 12.04.2 LTS !

Comment: You can also use `d-i preseed/early_command` instead of `run`.

Comment: Where the `run` actually executes is up for debate, it might be equivalent to `preseed/late_command` according to some open bugs, so if it doesn't work right in 16.04/18.04 try with `preseed/early_command`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to pass an arbitrary value to the kernel during a (PXE?) boot and then detect and react to it during the preseed? I think there may be better ways of accomplishing this but I'd have to know more about your specific scenario. The [Cobbler project](https://cobbler.github.io/) comes to mind though.

Regardless, another way to accomplish this may be to use a conditional include based on the hostname or cmdline that includes a config file with the appropriate mirror settings, as include files override values from any earlier file.

```
# More flexibly, this runs a shell command and if it outputs the names of
# preconfiguration files, includes those files. 
#d-i preseed/include_command \
#      string if [ "`hostname`" = bob ]; then echo bob.cfg; fi
```